# Serial communications over stlink with stm32f4discovery, is it possible?

Tags: serial-port, stm32, stm32f4discovery

I have the following: [STM32F407G-DISC1](https://www.digikey.com.au/product-detail/en/stmicro/STM32F407G-DISC1/497-16287-ND/5824404?utm_adgroup=Embedded+-+MCU+and+DSP&mkwid=s&pcrid=250109637033&pkw=&pmt=&pdv=c&productid=5824404&slid=&gclid=CjwKCAjwqarbBRBtEiwArlfEINS0E-tQv1ymlPWSQYM3PVKVcGMGNBb-5tOXRCElt6LDcTvJZgv5fBoC5GsQAvD_BwE). My goal is to communicate (sending strings back and forth) between my pc and the mcu over serial and I currently am able to do so using the micro-usb (otg) port, while powering separately using the mini-usb st-link port (so using two cables).

Is it possible to use the mini-usb port for serial communications? (eliminating one of the cables)

I have read the [user manual](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/70/fe/4a/3f/e7/e1/4f/7d/DM00039084.pdf/files/DM00039084.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00039084.pdf) and my interpretation is that this is not possible without physical modifications. But I am a beginner and would like to verify I am correct in this interpretation. I have researched thoroughly however most sources seem to not refer to this specific board and it is my understanding with the newer version of st-link it uses this should be achievable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible - just send the messages via the USART2

You need to solder those two wires as they screw up the design.

Comment: @Robert I have answered the asked question. He asked if it is possible to use ST-Link VCOM and how: by sending data via the USART2. Nothing else can be added

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. But the manual says "The ST-LINK/V2-A supports a virtual COM port (VCP) on U2 pin 12 (ST-LINK_TX) and U2
pin 13 (ST-LINK_RX) but these pins are not connected to the USART of the STM32F407
microcontroller for mbed support." And then suggests using flying wires or usart to usb dongle. Is this referring to something else?

Comment: @Gerard - sorry yes you need to solder them. They screw up the design. Other DISC1 boards do not need it. (actually all the modern boards with the ST-LINK with VCOM support)